# CakePHP Session Timeout

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

In CakePHP a the Session times out it, not unreasonably, trashes any custom data in the stored Session.

However it also sets up an Auth.redirect so after the user has been forced back to the login screen and completes the login, they are then (by default) redirected back to the page they were on before the session expired. This is problematic if that page relies on some of the custom data that was stored in the Session but is now no longer available.

My simple solution has been to force the user back to the home page for authenticated users by deleting the Auth.session key in the Session. But this isn't a particularly desirable behaviour. It would be preferable if I could return the user to the place they were before the Session timed out.

Nevertheless, I like the idea of a user having to re-authenticate if they abandon their Session for too long.

So, what seems to be needed is for CakePHP to require a re-authentication of the user but to not actually expire the underlying Session and this leads to a couple of questions:

1. Is there any way to have CakePHP require a re-authentication of the Session, as described, without timing out the session (i.e. setting a long timeout on the Session)?
2. Is there actually a better way to store the information required for page transitions (e.g. the ID of the parent record for a given model so that saveAssociated can be used) other than to store these in the Session?

Thank you for any guidance.